# Unable to load DLL 'curand64_80'

Tags: c#, aleagpu

This is my first time trying to run the Alea TK MNIST example on my machine.

I installed CUDA 8 and everything in accordance with http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_2/doc/installation.html

However running it I always get this error: `Unable to load DLL 'curand64_80': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

Even though I can clearly see the `curand64_80.dll` in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin`

I've set the configuration as such (app.config):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="aleaSettings" type="Alea.Settings, Alea"/>
  </configSections>
  <aleaSettings>
    <cuBLAS version="8.0"/>
    <cuRAND version="8.0"/>
  </aleaSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

This is the full exception stack trace:

```
   at Alea.DynamicInterop.curandCreateGenerator.Invoke(IntPtr , RngType )
   at A.cdbbf7f52ce1317681b2fa10b7329e78e.-ctor@386-309.Invoke(Unit _arg3)
   at Alea.cuRAND.Generator..ctor(FSharpOption`1 cc2af9506f3fc494fecea785eae58ff3b, FSharpOption`1 cdd5e91d5c509dec430918468c49a7937, RngType c23e4321fb7f1de7409a3cd12e2cd5890)
   at (FSharpOption`1 , FSharpOption`1 , RngType )
   at AleaTK.GpuContext.CreateRandomGenerator(PseudoRandomType type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at AleaTK.ExprImpl.PseudoRandomExpr`1.Execute(Assignment assignment, ILValue`1 output)
   at AleaTK.LExpr`1.Execute(Assignment assignment)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

What am I missing and how can I run the sample successfully?

Comment: Is the folder where the DLL resides in your PATH or is the DLL in the same folder where your executable resides? Are you targeting 32-bit rather than 64? (The DLL name and location indicate it's the 64-bit version of the DLL.)

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I just assumed the CUDA installation would take care of that... apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update the PATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/465509) to include `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin`

I assumed that the CUDA installation would update my PATH environment variable, but it didn't

Answer (score 1):

Alea GPU 3.0.2 is looking for CUDA toolkit 7.5 by default. You seem to use CUDA toolkit 8.0. You have to configure Alea GPU accordingly. Refer to the [documentation](http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_2/doc/faq.html#config_cuda_version) for details how to config the CUDA tookit version. Also make sure that you build and run 64 bit because several CUDA libraries are only available in 64bit. HTH.